# How to divide and load parts of Large Adobe AIR app for Android

Tags: android, flash, air, download, adobe

I want to create an app for Android but it will quite large. It will be larger than the 50MB offered by Google Play Store. This means that I need to find a way and break the app and load parts of it when I need them. Imagine it like minigames inside a bigger app.

It is not clear to me how to achieve this since every time on AIR, I can export and APK file for a mini-game let's say. Can I later download APKs and integrate them into my main app? How would this be possible? Another question that I have is: In order for a SWF to play on my app, it needs to be built by AIR for Android?

The best case would be to download content from In-App purchases and integrate in my app.
But these things are not so clear.

Thanks in advance for your help and support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse/Read APK file on Adobe Air Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267498/parse-read-apk-file-on-adobe-air-android)

Comment: I find it hard to answer your question since your assessment of the problem seems completely off. Is the code need to write your app going to be by itself more than 50M? I have published a 500M app on Android and my code was at max 12M, the rest was graphics and sounds which are easy to load apart which is what I had to do. I have a hard time imagining a piece of code (and I mean only code) that is bigger than 50M.

Comment: @BotMaster This is a good point. 50M (-10M for captive runtime) is 41 million characters. I find it highly unlikely that much code was written.

Comment: These are interesting comments but do not actually offer an answer to an existing situation for many devs.